# Dudas con el traspaso de datos

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, estoy realizando mi primer app en android studio en java y aprendiendo cada día, ahora me encuentro trabajando con los Fragment dentro de un activity, como lo menciona los desarrolladores de android, en este se creó cinco fragment que se llaman: datos, asegurado, siniestro, póliza y policial, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente que un edittext de fecha en el formulario de datos, y este sea rescatado a través del formulario de póliza, lo que tengo hecho a la fecha en el código del fragment de datos es el siguiente:

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import com.example.prueba1.R;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class datos extends Fragment {

EditText txtsiniestro,txtregistro1,txtpoliza,txtfechadenuncia,txtfechadesignacion,txtfechainspeccion,
txtanalista,txtliq,txtactivo8;

public datos() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_datos, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    txtsiniestro = view.findViewById(R.id.txtsiniestro);
    txtregistro1 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtregistro1);
    txtpoliza = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpoliza);
    txtfechadenuncia = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadenuncia);
    txtfechadesignacion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechadesignacion);
    txtfechainspeccion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechainspeccion);
    txtanalista = view.findViewById(R.id.txtanalista);
    txtliq = view.findViewById(R.id.txtliq);
    txtactivo8 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtactivo8);
    txtliq.setText("N° 2023-*-FVJ/VEH");

    txtregistro1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //llenarSpinner();
        }
    });

    txtfechadenuncia.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadenuncia.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechadesignacion.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechadesignacion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechadesignacion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechainspeccion.requestFocus();
                    traspaso();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechainspeccion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    datos.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechainspeccion.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtanalista.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtsiniestro.requestFocus();
}

private void traspaso() {
    Bundle datosAEnviar = new Bundle();
    datosAEnviar.putString("fecha", txtfechadesignacion.getText().toString());
    Fragment fragmento = new poliza();
    fragmento.setArguments(datosAEnviar);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.principaldatos, fragmento);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
}
```

este funciona bien, pero me automáticamente me aparece el fragment de la póliza, y eso es lo que no quiero ya que debe pasar antes por asegurado y siniestro y al pinchar el usuario el fragmento de la poliza que aparezca el dato de la fecha ya ingresado con anterioridad en el formulario denominado "datos", a continuación les presento lo que tengo hecho en el fragmento de la póliza:

```
package com.example.prueba1.Controlador;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentResultListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.example.prueba1.R;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpClient;
import com.loopj.android.http.AsyncHttpResponseHandler;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;

public class poliza extends Fragment {

public poliza() {

}

EditText txtfechainicio,txtfechatermino,et_descripcion,et_corredor,et_rut,et_cobertura,et_poliza,et_deducible,
        et_deducible1,et_deducible2,et_monto,txtfechainforme,et_tipo,et_marca,et_modelo,et_motor,et_chasis,et_ano,
        et_color,et_patente,txtfecha;
Spinner spcorredor,spcobertura,sptipo,spmarca,spmodelo;
private AsyncHttpClient cliente;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getParentFragmentManager().setFragmentResultListener("key", this, new FragmentResultListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFragmentResult(@NonNull String requestKey, @NonNull Bundle bundle) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poliza, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    txtfechainicio = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechainicio);
    txtfechatermino = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechatermino);
    et_descripcion = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdescripcion1);
    spcorredor = view.findViewById(R.id.spcorredor);
    cliente = new AsyncHttpClient();
    et_corredor = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcorredor);
    et_rut = view.findViewById(R.id.txtrut2);
    spcobertura = view.findViewById(R.id.spcobertura);
    et_cobertura = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcobertura);
    et_poliza = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpoliza1);
    et_deducible = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdeducible);
    et_deducible1= view.findViewById(R.id.txtdeducible1);
    et_deducible2 = view.findViewById(R.id.txtdeducible2);
    et_monto = view.findViewById(R.id.txtmonto);
    txtfechainforme = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfechainforme);
    sptipo = view.findViewById(R.id.sptipo);
    et_tipo = view.findViewById(R.id.txttipo);
    spmarca = view.findViewById(R.id.spmarca);
    et_marca = view.findViewById(R.id.txtmarca);
    spmodelo = view.findViewById(R.id.spmodelo);
    et_modelo = view.findViewById(R.id.txtmodelo);
    et_motor = view.findViewById(R.id.txtmotor);
    et_chasis = view.findViewById(R.id.txtchasis);
    et_ano = view.findViewById(R.id.txtano1);
    et_color = view.findViewById(R.id.txtcolor);
    et_patente = view.findViewById(R.id.txtpatente);
    txtfecha = view.findViewById(R.id.txtfecha);

    txtfechainicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    poliza.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechainicio.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    txtfechatermino.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    txtfechatermino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            int day = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            int month = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int year = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(
                    poliza.super.getActivity(), new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    txtfechatermino.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                    et_descripcion.requestFocus();
                }
            }, year, month, day);
            datePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });

    et_descripcion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            llenarSpinner();
        }
    });

    ArrayList<String> seleccion = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion.add("Seleccione");
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter (poliza.super.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, seleccion);
    spcorredor.setAdapter(adaptador);

    Bundle datosRecuperados = getArguments();
    if (datosRecuperados == null) {

        return;
    }
    String fecha1 = datosRecuperados.getString("fecha");
    txtfecha.setText(fecha1);
    txtfechainicio.requestFocus();
}

private void llenarSpinner(){
    try {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.86/oficina/buscar_corredores1.php";
        cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                if (statusCode == 200){
                    cargarSpinner(new String(responseBody));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {
                Log.d("WEB", "onFailure: " + statusCode + "\nError: " + error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void cargarSpinner (String respuesta) {
    ArrayList<Corredores> lista = new ArrayList<Corredores>();
    try {
        JSONArray jsonarreglo = new JSONArray (respuesta);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonarreglo.length(); i++) {
            Corredores c = new Corredores();
            c.setCorredor(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Nombre_Corredor"));
            c.setRut(jsonarreglo.getJSONObject(i).getString("Rut_Corredor"));
            lista.add(c);
        }
        ArrayAdapter<Corredores> a = new ArrayAdapter<Corredores>(poliza.super.getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, lista);
        spcorredor.setAdapter(a);
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        spcorredor.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long idl) {
                Corredores c = lista.get(position);
                String url = "http://192.168.1.86/oficina/buscar_corredores1.php?Nombre_Corredor="+c.getCorredor();
                cliente.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
                        Log.d("WEB", "onSuccess: " + statusCode);
                        if (statusCode == 200){
                            et_corredor.setText(lista.get(position).getCorredor());
                            et_rut.setText(lista.get(position).getRut());
                            Consultar();
                            spcobertura.requestFocus();
                        }
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable error) {

                    }
                });
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void Consultar (){
    ArrayList<String> seleccion1 = new ArrayList<>();
    seleccion1.add("Seleccione");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. Vehículos Motorizados");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat a Consecuencia de Riesgos de la Naturaleza");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. causados por la Propia Carga");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. a Consecuencia de Granizo");
    seleccion1.add("Daños a Terceros Causados por la Carga");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. a Consecuencia de Huelga y Terrorismo");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. a Consecuencia de Sismo");
    seleccion1.add("D. Mat. a Consecuencia de Actos Maliciosos");
    seleccion1.add("Robo, Hurto, uso No Autorizado");
    seleccion1.add("Robo de Accesorios");
    ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador1 = new ArrayAdapter (poliza.super.getActivity(), R.layout.spcobertura,seleccion1);
    spcobertura.setAdapter(adaptador1);
    spcobertura.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            et_cobertura.setText(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            et_poliza.requestFocus();
        }
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
}
}
```

ojala que me halla explicado bien lo que pretendo hacer, creo que el código para recuperar un dato está bien hecho porque me funciona, pero lo que quiero es que el usuario se dirija al fragment de la póliza y muestre el dato recién y no una vez que lo digite en el fragment de datos me muestre el fragment de la póliza, ojala que se pueda hacer ya que la solución que estoy viendo es realizar todo en un solo formulario (activity) y del cual va a salir muy largo para el usuario y no muy práctico, y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Amigos por la duda que tenía la encontré y para alguno que tengan el mismo problema que el mío y que somo nuevos en estas lides lo realice de la siguiente manera el private del traspaso hice lo siguiente:

```
private void traspaso() {
    Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("fecha", txtfechadesignacion.getText().toString());
    editor.apply();
}
```

y en el fragment de póliza hice lo siguiente en el onViewCreated:

```
Context context = getActivity();
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Mis_preferences",context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String dato = sharedPreferences.getString("fecha","No hay dato");
    txtfecha.setText(dato);
```

ojala que le sirva de ayuda para todos, ya que en esta misma página leí un artículo y la encontré.
por otro lado se me olvido mencionar que en el build.gradle deben ingresar la siguiente librería:

```
implementation 'androidx.fragment:fragment:1.5.6'
```

ojala que les sirva como a mi.

Comment: Esto no es para "traspasar" o enviar datos, es para guardar en preferencias y leerlas en otro Fragment de tu aplicación.

Comment: @Jorgesys eso es lo que pretendía hacer, ya que si te diste cuenta en la parte del primer código que subí en el traspaso me mostraba el dato de la fecha y me kostraba el fragment de la póliza, pero el usuario como dije anteriormente debe ingresar dos fragment antes de llegar al fragment de póliza